# How to make this Facebook SVG icon?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have to do it like this
[image]

I want to make this icon from two elements. There are should be blue background and svg. How can I make this?
This is my code:

```css
.facebook_logo {
    fill: white;
    stroke: black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
    <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="0 0 23.101 23.101">
        <path d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="facebook_logo">
    <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Go to [Facebook Brand Resources](https://en.facebookbrand.com/facebookapp/) centre and download their pre-made genuine SVGs. It saves you time. And creating your own FB branding stuff is illegal and in the (unlikely) event that you're discovered by Facebook would be very hard to win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using `flex` on a parent `div` + `hover`;

```css
.facebook_logo {
    fill: white;
    stroke: black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
}

.facebook_ {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transition: .3s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.facebook_:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
            <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="0 0 23.101 23.101">
                <path d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
            </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="facebook_">
<svg class="facebook_logo">
    <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
</svg>
<div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use same width & height and add some padding.

```css
.facebook_logo {
  fill: white;
  stroke: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px; /* your icon's total width & height is 40px  */
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<svg display="none">
            <symbol id="facebook" viewBox="0 0 23.101 23.101">
                <path d="M8.258,4.458c0-0.144,0.02-0.455,0.06-0.931c0.043-0.477,0.223-0.976,0.546-1.5c0.32-0.522,0.839-0.991,1.561-1.406
                C11.144,0.208,12.183,0,13.539,0h3.82v4.163h-2.797c-0.277,0-0.535,0.104-0.768,0.309c-0.231,0.205-0.35,0.4-0.35,0.581v2.59h3.914
                c-0.041,0.507-0.086,1-0.138,1.476l-0.155,1.258c-0.062,0.425-0.125,0.819-0.187,1.182h-3.462v11.542H8.258V11.558H5.742V7.643
                h2.516V4.458z"/>
            </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="facebook_logo">
    <use xlink:href="#facebook"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg id=FaceBookLogo width=100px viewBox='0 0 300 300'>
  <rect fill='#3b5998' width='100%' height='100%' rx='15%'/>
  <path fill='white' d='M110 80c0-1 0-5 1-9 0-5 2-10 6-15 3-5 8-10 16-14 7-4
                        18-6 31-6h38v42h-28c-3 0-5 1-8 3-2 2-3 4-3 6v26h39c0 
                        5-1 10-1 15l-1 13c-1 4-1 8-2 12h-35v115h-52v-115
                        h-25v-39h25v-32z'/>
</svg>

<style>
  #FaceBookLogo rect{
    fill:var(--FBblue,#3b5998);
  }
  #FaceBookLogo path{
    fill:var(--FBwhite,white)
  }
  #FaceBookLogo:hover{
    --FBblue:green;
    --FBwhite:gold;
    width:150px;
  }
</style>
```

I used https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ to multiply the path definition by a scale 10 to get rid of all decimal positions and still maintain some accuracy in the letter F outline.

Now play with the 300 viewBox size to scale the letter, and change `M110 80` at the start of the path (x y) to position the letter.